# Orbeon database migration

Tags: orbeon

I have a running instance of Orbeon with some forms already created on it.

Now I have installed a new Orbeon instance (with latest version) in another CentOS 7 server and I want to migrate the forms from the old instance.

I have tried by taking the content of exist-data from the first instance and copying it to my new instance, however, the forms are not being loaded in the new instance.

I have been looking for it but I don't find any information about how to do it.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying ONLY the .dbx files from directory exist-data to the new instance was enough to have finally the database migrated between versions.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found a solution to the issue.